# Webcam automatically capturing (Emgu.cv) c#

Tags: c#, winforms, webcam, emgucv

I have a project where when user login wrong for 3 times in login form, the webcam will start capturing automatically. It successfully saves the image in the database but there is one error which is Object Reference not set to an instance of an object. I know that there are a lot of questions and answers to this but I still can't solve it. Another problem is, when I just debug from the webcam form, it runs perfectly without the error message but when I debug from login form, the error appears. Another thing is it doesn't show the line of the error but I am sure that it comes somewhere from here:

```
private void webcam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           if ((imagecapture == null))
           {
               try
               {
                   imagecapture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }

           }
           Application.Idle += new EventHandler(loadimage);
       }
```

and this is the loadimage()

```
public void loadimage(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           try
           {
               Emgu.CV.Mat imageviewer = this.imagecapture.QueryFrame();
               pictureBox1.Image = imageviewer.Bitmap;

               MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
               pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
               byte[] picture = ms.ToArray();
               connection.Open();
               DateTime dtime = DateTime.Now;

               string qry = "INSERT INTO WebcamPhoto (ImageData,DateAndTime)  VALUES(@ImageData,@dt)";

               //Initialize SqlCommand object for insert.
               SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, connection);

               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ImageData", picture);
               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", dtime);
               cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
               connection.Close();
               imagecapture.Dispose();

               //Close form and return to list or images.
               this.Close();
           }
           catch (NullReferenceException ex)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
           }
       }
```

I have tried to put return and the error message is gone but the image is not saved in the database even though the webcam is working.

```
private void webcam_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {

           if ((imagecapture == null))
           {
               try
               {
                   imagecapture = new Emgu.CV.VideoCapture();
               }
               catch (Exception ex)
               {
                   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
               }
               return;
           }
           Application.Idle += new EventHandler(loadimage);
       }
```

Comment: Probably unrelated: You really should be using [`using`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) more.

Comment: Instead of showing a Messagebox with the exception message, write it to console or a logfile and add the stacktrace. There you can see which line is the culprit, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after few days finaly I found the answer myself. How? I try to change the way I wrote the code line by line and test it everytime I change the code and finally I found the culprit. So the culprit is:

```
public void loadimage(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
         //my other code.....
               imagecapture.Dispose(); <<<----here 

       }
```

So I change it to

```
    private void ReleaseData()
    {
        if (imagecapture !=null)
        {
            imagecapture.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

and now the problem is solved :)